# How to check the checkbox with the data retrieved

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm able to insert the checked values to Db along with other values.Here I try to display the fetched values from the DB.The issue faced is, I want the selected value's checkbox to be checked and display the other values which I couldn't do it . Can anyone help me how to do it. I have attached a plunker how my current screen looks like.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="field in fields" name="slotSelection">
    <td align="center">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.checked">{{field.name}} 
    </td>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="time" ng-options="time for time in field.timeslots">
        <option value="">select</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="interval" ng-blur="setTimeSlots(interval, field)">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

[Code in Plnk](https://plnkr.co/edit/UJJ2tTuWlElHydk0c3YD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use ngChecked option of Angular JS

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="*expression*">
```

If the *expression* is truthy, then the checked attribute will be set on the element

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="field.checked">{{field.name}}
```

[Sample Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7aaoj9FdeVUuRFz6FDAW?p=preview)

Comment: Please check if the field.checked returns a boolean. I have added sample plnkr to the answer. Please check.